# Adding an image swap to click event

Tags: jquery

I'm looking for a way to incorporate into this click function - to swap the button image to a "active" image. Each button is a unique image and has a unique active.
It's a sub-menu that currently functions to add/hide the paragraphs below when each button is clicked

**JS:**

```
 $(".button a").click(function(e) {
    var id = this.hash;
    $("#b-text div:visible").not(id).fadeOut(function(){
        $(id).fadeIn();
    });
    e.preventDefault();
});
$("#b-text div:not(#button1)").hide();
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="buttons">

    <div>
        <h2>Title</h2>
        <div class="button">
            <a href="#button1"><img src="img/button1-a.png" alt="" /></a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div>
        <h2>Title</h2>
        <div class="button">
            <a href="#button2"><img src="img/button2.png" alt="" /></a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div>
        <h2>Title</h2>
        <div class="button">
            <a href="#button3"><img src="img/button3.png" alt="" /></a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div>
        <h2>Title</h2>
        <div class="button">
            <a href="#button4"><img src="img/button4.png" alt="" /></a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div>
        <h2>Title</h2>
        <div class="button">
            <a href="#button5"><img src="img/button5.png" alt="" /></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<div id="b-text">

    <div id="button1">
        <p>text here</p>
    </div>

    <div id="button2">
        <p>text</p>
    </div>

    <div id="button3">
        <p>text</p>
    </div>

    <div id="button4">
        <p>text</p>
    </div>

    <div id="button5">
        <p>text</p>
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `<img>` tag  use just your `<a>` tags
and to prevent the browser to load a new image (the active one)
I'd suggest you to use the ***sprite*** technique and **`background-image`** for example:

```
 __________________________________
|                |                 |
|  normal image  |   focus image   |
|________________|_________________|
```

**Adding/removing a CSS `.active` with jQuery will change the background-position of every bg-image**

```
/* all buttons */
.button a {
   display: inline-block ;
   width:  120px ;
   height: 80px  ;
   background-position: 0 0;
}
.button a.active { /* toggle this class in jQuery */
   background-position: -120px 0;
}

/* buttons defaults */
.button a[href='#button1']{
   background-image: url('button1.png');
}
.button a[href='#button2']{
   background-image: url('button2.png');
}
```

jQuery

```
var $buttons_A = $('.button a');

$buttons_A.click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();   // Prevent browser follow link, jump etc
    $buttons_A.removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    // other stuff here... 
});
```

Comment: Thank you, I ended up using a bit of both answers :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is my approach to the problem:

**[Demo at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/promatik/P2DPJ/)**.

Instead of the native `active` property, use a css class (`.active`) and switch the class in the buttons.

**CSS:**

```
.button {
    background-image: ...
    background-position: -10px -80px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.button.active {
    background-image: ...
    background-position: -200px -80px;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="buttons">
    <div>
        <h2>Title</h2>
        <div class="button active" adr="#button1"></div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h2>Title</h2>
        <div class="button" adr="#button2"></div>
    </div>
    ...
```

**JS:**

```
$(".button").click(function(e) {
    var id = $(this).attr('adr');

    $('.button').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you - that's exactly what I was after

Answer (score 0):

you have not put any text in anchor tag. Check the below demo fiddle for your solution you are looking for.

```
<div id="buttons">

    <div>
        <h2>Title</h2>
        <div class="button">
            <a href="#button1"><img src="img/button1-a.png" alt="" />link 1</a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div>
        <h2>Title</h2>
        <div class="button">
            <a href="#button2"><img src="img/button2.png" alt="" />link 2</a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div>
        <h2>Title</h2>
        <div class="button">
            <a href="#button3"><img src="img/button3.png" alt="" />link 3</a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div>
        <h2>Title</h2>
        <div class="button">
            <a href="#button4"><img src="img/button4.png" alt="" />link 4</a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div>
        <h2>Title</h2>
        <div class="button">
            <a href="#button5"><img src="img/button5.png" alt="" />link 5</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<div id="b-text">

    <div id="button1">
        <p>text here 1</p>
    </div>

    <div id="button2">
        <p>text 2</p>
    </div>

    <div id="button3">
        <p>text 3</p>
    </div>

    <div id="button4">
        <p>text 4</p>
    </div>

    <div id="button5">
        <p>text 5</p>
    </div>

</div>
```

If you want to show/hide text on click of heading than here is the answer.

```
$("h2").click(function(e) {

    var id = $(this).next().find('a').attr('href');
    console.log(id)
    $("#b-text div:visible").not(id).fadeOut(function(){
        $(id).fadeIn();
    });
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Fiddle Demo for h2 click: [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/aSaLR/2/)

http://jsfiddle.net/aSaLR/

Comment: Sorry, I probably explained it poorly. The anchors are intentionally empty, the img itself is all I wanted to anchor and the <h2> sits above the button to describe it